# Не устанавливается иконка для приложения Delphi

Tags: delphi, icon, delphi-xe

Программирую в Delphi не первый год, а уже наверное полтора десятилетия.
Но вот вопрос - не устанавливается иконка. Т.е. взял старый проект, переделал его немного, а позже заметил, что слетела иконка приложения.
Я естественно постарался поставить её стандартными средствами `"Project" > "Options" > "Application" > "Load Icon"`.
Она там отобразилась - всё вроде нормально, но вот при компиляции всё равно не "вшивается" в приложение.
Как быть? И что это за глюк?
Может какой-то файл как-то почистить редактором кода?
Информация о иконке в каком файле приложения записывается?

---

Данная информация храниться в файле проекта `.res`
Подставил из другого проекта - иконка поменялась на иконку из того проекта.
Создал новое приложение, взял от туда `.res`-файл, подставил в проект, ситуация повторилась... Иконка стандартная от Delphi и не изменяется.
Как всё-таки быть?

Comment: зачастую это бывает глюк винды - слишком кеширует иконки файлов и не планирует менять на правильную - зашитую в приложение. Решается (т.е. определяется - действительно ли иконка не та) просмотром свойств файла или копированием в другую папку. И - иконка указана для нужной Build configuration?

Comment: @kami, Разобрался, данную информацию хранит в себе файл [имя_проекта].res
Но вот теперь второй вопрос - как его создать новый?

Comment: он генерируется автоматически на основании данных в dproj. В частности, за иконку отвечает тег из dproj (емнип) Icon_MainIcon. При сборке генерируется файл vrc, потом - res.  Кстати - никаких ворнингов нет о duplicated resource?

Comment: Если при открытии проекта файл [имя_проекта].res отсутствует, то он будет создан заново автоматически. Просто удалите его и переоткройте проект

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, да вот от того и задал вопрос про его создание, так как при компиляции пишет not found такой-то res.

Comment: закройте ide, удалите dproj, откройте проект и выставьте настройки (иконку и версию) по новой.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

1. Удалить файл `.res`. Delphi создаст его заново.
2. Посмотреть свойства `.ехе` файла в самой винде, там должна отображаться новая иконка. Если она отобразилась, значит на самом деле иконка новая.
   Хотя в проводнике или другом файловом менеджере, который есть у вас, она может отображаться по старому. Тогда п.3
3. Закрыть и открыть заново файловый менеджер либо перезагрузить винду.
   У меня была такая история, когда я бился с этой иконкой, а Тотал-Командер все равно не отображал. Закрыл-открыл Тотал и все отобразилось, но нервов потратил уже прилично :)